# Building java from MSBuild

Tags: java, msbuild, integration

We are using MSBuild to run our build which compiles and outputs a number of .NET projects/assemblies. Now we are faced with the need to also include a java version of on of our assemblies and are unsure how we should go about integrating the building of this java source into MSBuild.

There is always the option to shell out to a command prompt and have it perform the compilation and jar'ing manually, but are there any other and more elegant ways to go about consuming java building in MSBuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) is the perfect thing.  Easy, works. Not sure if that's what you mean by "Shell out".

Comment: 'Shell out' was actually a call to the Exec task....only it would require us to do a lot of manual typing and keeping the java file references correct. Was looking for a way to take the human factor out...

Comment: Instead of calling javac and jar directly, you can call ant and speficy the Java part in a build.xml which you keep as part of your code base.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Microsoft's Team Foundation Server Build Extensions Power Tool December 2011](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d7c8577-54b8-47ce-82a5-8649f579dcb6)

It has an Ant task for MSBuild.

The documentation seems scarce but it's derived from [Teamprise Build Extensions](http://labs.teamprise.com/build/extensions.html) which has a nice pdf manual.

@tsu1980's post has a nice MSBuild code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own msbuild task to compile java is possible (I have made one to compile VB6 code with MSBuild), but if it is a good idea is another question.. ([YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it) and all that)

If shelling out to the command line does work it may just be an OK thing to do.

My gut is saying shell out to an Ant process since Ant knows a little bit more about Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write custom task to call 'Ant' from MSBuild.

https://github.com/sumi2/AntTask

You can call Ant script like following

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <JavaHome>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\build\tools\jdk1.6.0_25</JavaHome>
  <AntHome>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\build\tools\apache-ant-1.8.2</AntHome>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Call Ant with 'jar' target. -->
<Ant 
  BuildFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\YourJavaProject\build.xml"
  Target="jar"
  AntHome="$(AntHome)"
  JavaHome="$(JavaHome)"
 />
```